# Play 2.5 priming the web service

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a restful web service developed using play 2.5 framework. 
I want to prime my web service on start by calling itself. This is to make sure that my service is perfectly up and running.

The approach i am taking is using [eagerBinding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings). But the code inside the class injected using eager binding gets executed just before the app starts

Here is what my eagerbinding code looks like

```
@Singleton
class PrimingMe @Inject()(ws: WSClient) {

  isServicePrimed

  def isServicePrimed: Boolean = {

    println("PRIME ME!!!")
    val response = ws.url("http://localhost:9000/index").get
      .map {
        response =>
          response.status match {
            case 200 => true
            case _ => false
          }
      }

    try {
      Await.result(response, 5.second)
    } catch {
      case _ => false
    }

  }

}


class ServiceInjectionModule extends AbstractModule {

  def configure(): Unit = {

    bind(classOf[PrimingMe]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

Inside application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "util.ServiceInjectionModule"
```

I want to prime my application with a dummy service call so that when the real traffic starts coming all db connections are made. Currently my first api call to the service takes much longer than the usual. What other options do i have to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

No Purpose is not defeated. Eager loading still works as expected.

Ensure that the `util.ServiceInjectionModule` is the first module to load by declaring it on the top in the application.conf file.

I have done a small experiment after seeing your question to prove this

This is how my module looks like. It is declared in the root directory and as Module is in the root director i.e app, You do not have to explicitly add to the application.conf

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
   override def configure() = {
    //It is very important for this call to be on the top.
    bind(classOf[Initialize]).asEagerSingleton()
   }
}
```

Eager singleton

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import com.google.inject.Singleton
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

@Singleton
class Initialize @Inject() (wsClient: WSClient) {

  hit()

  def hit(): Unit = {
    val f = wsClient.url("http://www.google.com").get()
    val result = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
    Logger.info(s"status: ${result.status}")
  }
}
```

output:

```
[info] application - status: 200
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
```

From the above output you can see that Module has loaded and `hit()` is called.

Comment: Why would it have to be the first module?

Comment: thats right it works,  i had to start my application with sbt compile start. however the problem is that i cant call 'myself' as this just before the service starts. let me rephrase the question.